# How to remove fields from user creation form in django

Tags: django

I am creating an app in django with postgressql. So I am creating my custom user model with own fields.BUt when I go to my database their are many fields like first name , last name, id. I dont want to see those field, I only want to see the fields that I am writing in my custom model.
Edit: I am adding the model

```
class TableUsers(AbstractUser):
    username = None
 
    phoneNumberRegex = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]*$', 'Enter a valid Phone number')
    user_id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    user_phone = models.CharField(validators = [phoneNumberRegex],max_length = 11, unique = True,)

    user_fname = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
    user_lname = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
    user_country = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
   
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user_phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_phone)
```

Comment: You mean in your admin ?

Comment: no, Just from my CustomUser model, because I am writing  my own fields.

Comment: Provide your model field in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misconception of what extending the user model should be.

First of all you should rename your model to something more explicit such as **UserExtra** or even **User**, it is totally fine.

Second of all you are adding field that are **already provided** for you by your Abstract User, so you don't have to add the last_name, first_name, id just the ones that are not already in the Abstract User.

Finally you should not try to remove the field provided by Django, they are tightly tied with Django itself and should not be removed.

See [Abstract User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/)

Comment: thanks alot, can I change the name just for the display in database, actually my database has everything like, user_name, user_phone, user_coutry, but it is only displaying id there, I want user prefix with it.

Comment: It is consider bad practice to alter the field provided by Django, if for some reason they do not meet your requirements you can add extra fields to your AbstactUser. If you want to change the display of those fields for your users you can add a verbose attribute to your fields https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names

Comment: perfect, you clear my all doubts. thanks man